# Bootstrap Container size not changing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

Hi i recently installed bootstrap.I tried to change my container max size to 980px but then here in my website it doesnt change.Can any one help me out?
Thanks in advance
here is my website :http://mywebsyt.net63.net/

Comment: Where did you try to change it? I don't see any additional styles for .container. Just the standard bootstrap css. BTW, if you want to customize/override existing styles, you need to add a custom style sheet.

Comment: i downloaded the customised file from bootstrap. BTW can you please tell me what to add the custom css file? pls

Answer (score 0):

If you want the container to be the max width of 980, you will need to adjust the largest media query. In your custom.css file add the following rule:

```
@media (min-width:1200px){
.container {
    width: 980px
 }
}
```

You now have 4 css links. Basically you want the first css file to be the one from bootstrap, the second one to be your custom css.I would change the code for these

```
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsyt.net63.net/user-content/templates/tinystudioz/public/css/custom.css">
```

Remove the other css files

Answer (score -1):

Seems your container class is outside the body tag.